# channel.history is no longer working correctly

Tags: python, discord.py

So I had a part of my discord bot in which you were able to save part of the chat as a txt file using channel.history. I hadn't touched this part of my code in a while and when coming back to it, the code returns the error "'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'.

I have tried using channel.history in simpler form with it still not working.

```
  if message.content.startswith("historytest"):
    messages = await message.channel.history(limit=5).flatten()
    await message.channel.send(messages)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [migration to v2.0 page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator), the way of using [`channel.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=history#discord.abc.Messageable.history) changed when `v2.0` released.

This is the way you are supposed to use `channel.history()` now (or any other method that returns an [asynchronous iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterator)):

```
if message.content.startswith("historytest"):
    async for message in message.channel.history(limit=5):
        print(message.content)
```

or if you prefer a flatten list instead:

```
if message.content.startswith("historytest"):
    messages = [message.content async for message in message.channel.history(limit=5)]
    print('\n'.join(messages))
```